# I want to be able to populate cphPayor.payor_name field. I'm getting null values in cphPayor.payor_name. What is wrong with my query below?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT        
    dbo.leasegis(cm.class, cm.nbr, cm.suffix) AS leasegis, 
    cm.class, cm.nbr, cm.suffix AS suffix, 
    dbo.format_cns(cm.class, cm.nbr, cm.suffix) AS label, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cm.begin_dt, 101) AS begindt, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cm.expire_dt, 101) AS expiredt, 
    aaclc.app_descr, aaclc.app_con_abbrev, aaclc.app_con_lcd, 
    cla.lseacres, acm.applicant_name AS customer_name, acm.descr, 
    cpsc.production_status_descr AS production_status, 
    cphr.document_dt AS document_dt_roy, 
    cphrm.document_dt AS document_dt_min_roy,  
    cphrent.document_dt AS document_dt_rent, cphPayor.payor_name
FROM            
    dbo.app_contr_mast AS acm 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.contr_master AS cm ON acm.class = cm.class 
                           AND acm.nbr = cm.nbr  
                           AND acm.suffix = cm.suffix 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.all_app_con_l_cd AS aaclc ON acm.app_con_lcd = aaclc.app_con_lcd   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.cnsd_lse_acres_vw AS cla ON cm.class = cla.class 
                                 AND cm.nbr = cla.nbr 
                                 AND cm.suffix = cla.suffix 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.contr_production_status_cd AS cpsc ON cm.production_status_cd = cpsc.production_status_cd 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT        
         class, nbr, suffix, MAX(document_dt) AS document_dt
     FROM            
         dbo.cash_payment_hist
     WHERE        
         (revenue_cd = 1401) AND (document_dt >= DATEADD(m, - 14, GETDATE()))
     GROUP BY 
         class, nbr, suffix, revenue_cd) AS cphr ON cm.class = cphr.class 
                                                AND cm.nbr = cphr.nbr 
                                                AND cm.suffix = cphr.suffix 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT        
         class, nbr, suffix, MAX(document_dt) AS document_dt
     FROM            
         dbo.cash_payment_hist AS cash_payment_hist_1
     WHERE        
         (revenue_cd = 1404) AND (document_dt >= DATEADD(m, - 18, GETDATE()))
     GROUP BY 
         class, nbr, suffix, revenue_cd) AS cphrm ON cm.class = cphrm.class 
                                                 AND cm.nbr = cphrm.nbr 
                                                 AND cm.suffix = cphrm.suffix 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT        
         class, nbr, suffix, MAX(document_dt) AS document_dt
     FROM            
         dbo.cash_payment_hist AS cash_payment_hist_2
     WHERE        
         (revenue_cd = 1301) AND (document_dt >= DATEADD(m, - 18, GETDATE()))
     GROUP BY 
         class, nbr, suffix, revenue_cd) AS cphrent ON cm.class = cphrent.class 
                                                   AND cm.nbr = cphrent.nbr 
                                                   AND cm.suffix = cphrent.suffix 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP (1) class, nbr, suffix, payor_name
     FROM dbo.cash_payment_hist AS cash_payment_hist_3
     WHERE (revenue_cd IN (1301, 1401, 1404))
     ORDER BY document_dt DESC) AS cphPayor ON cm.class = cphrent.class 
                                            AND cm.nbr = cphrent.nbr 
                                            AND cm.suffix = cphrent.suffix
WHERE        
    (cm.record_status = 1)
```

Comment: There is a code format button in the question editor which makes code readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There's not enough information in your question for anyone to be able to answer, I'm afraid.  Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for some very good guidance on how to improve your question (and by "improve" I mean "make it more likely that you'll get assistance")

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you don't have any records in `cash_payment_hist` with a `revenue_cd` value of 1301, 1401, or 1404, combined with the fact that the `On` clause of that `Left Outer Join` that creates `cphPayor` references the alias `cphrent`, not `cphPayor`.